# Solve Friedmann equation for non-zero curvature and non-zero cosmological constant

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, curvature, cosmological-constant

I tried to find an elegant way to solve (without approximating for low densities)

$$\dot{R}^2=\frac{8 \pi G}{3 c^2} \rho R^2-k c^2+\frac{c^2 \Lambda}{3} R^2$$

for $k=\pm 1$ and $\Lambda \neq 0$ (one time considering $\Lambda>0$ and another time considering $\Lambda<0$) and without using calculus software. I wasn't able to find that case in any of my General Relativity textbooks.

We assume that $R$ depends explicitly of $t$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And how would that help me to solve this differential equation with squared terms.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\rho$ is a function of $R$ only and does not explicitly depend on time, we can write
$$\dot{R}= \frac{dR}{dt} = \sqrt{\frac{8\pi G}{3c^2} \rho(R) R^2 - kc^2 + \frac{c^2\Lambda}{3} R^2}$$
$$\int_{R_0}^R\frac{dR'}{\sqrt{\frac{8\pi G}{3c^2} \rho(R') R'^2 - kc^2 + \frac{c^2\Lambda}{3} R'^2}} = \int_{t_0}^t dt' = t - t_0$$
The problem is solving the integral on the left-hand side. Depending on how the density behaves as a function of $R$, this integral may or may not have an analytical solution.

You need to specify which mass-energy components you want to consider. E.g. for nonrelativistic matter, we have $\rho \propto R^{-3}$ and for photons $\rho \propto R^{-4}$.

Comment: Sadly i'm looking for the resolution where $R$ depends explicitly on time....

Comment: @Vincent ISOZ: what are you talking about, he gave you the expression for dR/dt so there is your R dendending on t, you just have to integrate. The analytical solutions depend on the density models. For the simplest case of ΩK=1-ΩΛ see [here](http://relativity.yukterez.net/85.html#z) where you have the analytical solution for a(t), for R(0) just multiply your R0 with a(t). If you want more Ωs you have to solve numerically, see [here](http://relativity.yukterez.net/FLRW.functions.html#5)

Comment: @Yukterez Seperation of variables only works if the right-hand side does not depend explicitly on time.

Comment: @VincentISOZ Out of curiousity: In what cosmological model would $\rho$ explicitly depend on time and not only the scale factor?

Comment: @LenardKasselmann In what cosmological model? In a model I'm investigating for fun as hobby.

Comment: @VincentISOZ In that case, I'm not aware of a single strategy for solving the Friedmann equation. You will get different types of differential equations depending on the form of $\rho(t)$ and there is probably no recipe that will work for all of them.

Comment: @LenardKasselmann Ok Thanks for your help anyway.